# How to replace multiple characters in the same string?

Tags: string, go

I am not very versed in programming in general so please cut me some slack here.
Is there a more elegant way to tackle this process of replacing multiple characters in a string?

```
strings.ReplaceAll(strings.ReplaceAll(strings.ReplaceAll(strings.ReplaceAll(strings.ReplaceAll(strings.ReplaceAll(strings.ReplaceAll(strings.ReplaceAll(strings.ReplaceAll(godiacritics.Normalize(strings.ToLower(articles[i].Name)), "-", "_"), " ", "_"), ",", "_"), ".", ""), "/", ""), "€", ""), "%", ""), "12", "halb"), "14", "viertel")
```

Answer (score 14):

Create a single [`strings.Replacer`](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Replacer) which contains all replaceable pairs:

```
r := strings.NewReplacer(
    "-", "_",
    " ", "_",
    ",", "_",
    ".", "",
    "/", "",
    "€", "",
    "%", "",
    "12", "halb",
    "14", "viertel",
)
```

And use it like this:

```
s2 := r.Replace(godiacritics.Normalize(strings.ToLower(articles[i].Name)))
```

`strings.Replacer` performs all replaces in a single step (it iterates over the string once). It's also safe for concurrent use, create the `Replacer` onces and reuse it whenever / wherever needed.

Example code to test it:

```
s := "test- ,./€%:12 14"
s2 := strings.ReplaceAll(strings.ReplaceAll(strings.ReplaceAll(strings.ReplaceAll(strings.ReplaceAll(strings.ReplaceAll(strings.ReplaceAll(strings.ReplaceAll(strings.ReplaceAll(s, "-", "_"), " ", "_"), ",", "_"), ".", ""), "/", ""), "€", ""), "%", ""), "12", "halb"), "14", "viertel")
fmt.Println(s2)

r := strings.NewReplacer(
    "-", "_",
    " ", "_",
    ",", "_",
    ".", "",
    "/", "",
    "€", "",
    "%", "",
    "12", "halb",
    "14", "viertel",
)

s3 := r.Replace(s)
fmt.Println(s3)
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/TedEkYfds6-)):

```
test___:halb_viertel
test___:halb_viertel
```